# Calculating Average Ride Length

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following code to calculate the average ride_length:

```
SELECT avg(ride_length) FROM new_schema.`202004-divvy-tripdata`
```

However, this results in a decimal value (0.10509347284386551) and for some reason I am unable to change the datatype. It is currently set as `TEXT`. When I attempt to change to `TIME()` I get the following error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1292: Incorrect time value: '################################################################################################################################' for column 'ride_length' at row 2420
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `new_schema`.`202004-divvy-tripdata` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ride_length` `ride_length` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: The decimal value is not a valid time that's why you get an error.

Comment: You must first convert/update your columns to a proper `Time` format which is `HH:mm:ss`  in order to alter the table.